# Auto update Bundle in Apache Felix OSGi Framework

Tags: java, apache, frameworks, osgi

For Apache Felix OSGi Framework, is there a way to watch for bundle changes and automatically update those bundles instead of having to update it manually in the gogo shell?

Answer (score 0):

The Felix FileInstaller does this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on container such as Karaf, you can do a :

```
dev:watch <bundleNumber>
```

It automatically update the bundle if a new one is detected in your local repo (useful for testing/hotfixing snapshot installed in local).

Comment: I read about "Karaf" but unfortunately, it's not being utilized. Thanks for the suggestion.